# Unable to open Project File of SSRS 2008 into Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I have SSRS 2008 R2 Project and Solution File. I use BIDS 2009 for development. Now we are planning to switch to Visual Studio 2012 for development.

After installing Visual Studio 2012 with Sql Server Data Tools , I opened the existing solution file in Visual Studio 2012 ..... The popup will do One-Way Upgrade to solution file but Visual Studio 2012 is not supporting the Project File. It is giving me unsupported error message.

I can still open the solution file but can't load project file thus unable to do the development work in VS 2012.

Help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Ally

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio 2012 does not open SQL Server 2012 SSRS projects.  Visual Studio 2010 add on to SQL Server 2012 called Business Intelligence Development Studio(BIDS) does.  You can check if you have it under All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2012 > SQL Server Data Tools.  Add on for Visual Studio for 'SQL Server Data Tools' adds ability to do database design work like 'SQL Management Studio'.  It is weird but basically BIDS is for SSRS, SSAS, and SSIS.  While they work inside Visual Studio they are an add on you get from SQL Server installs.

SQL Server 2005 and 2008 work with the SAME year of Visual Studio.  SQL 2012 got out I believe before VS 2012 so it works with VS 2010.  If you don't have BIDS 2010 you can easily get it by getting SQL Server 2012 with advanced tools which includes all the BIDS development IDE.